# ES query to group by parent_id

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the below data in my elasticsearch. I would like to query these data with group.

```
{
   "id" : "001",
   "parent_id" : "001",
   "name" : "test001"
},
{
   "id" : "002",
   "parent_id" : "001",
   "name" : "test002"
},
{
   "id" : "003",
   "parent_id" : "001",
   "name" : "test003"
}
{
   "id" : "004",
   "parent_id" : "004",
   "name" : "test004"
}
```

Here is my expected format:

```
{
   "id" : "001",
   "parent_id" : "001",
   "name" : "test001"
   "children": [
   {
     "id" : "002",
     "parent_id" : "001",
     "name" : "test002"
   },
   {
     "id" : "003",
     "parent_id" : "001",
     "name" : "test003"
   }
  ]
},
{
   "id" : "004",
   "parent_id" : "004",
   "name" : "test004"
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this using elastic search query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `parent_id` is of the [`keyword` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword-field-type), and/or has a [multi-field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) similar to:

```json
"parent_id" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {          <---
      "type" : "keyword"    
    }
  }
}
```

you could first [group](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) all your documents by `parent_id.keyword` and then list all the children (including `#001`) using a [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```json
POST my-index/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.buckets.key,aggregations.*.buckets.children.hits.hits._source
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_parent_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parent_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "children": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "id.keyword": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_parent_id" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "001",
          "children" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : "001",
                    "parent_id" : "001",
                    "name" : "test001"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : "002",
                    "parent_id" : "001",
                    "name" : "test002"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : "003",
                    "parent_id" : "001",
                    "name" : "test003"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "004",
          "children" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : "004",
                    "parent_id" : "004",
                    "name" : "test004"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also sort the children by a metric of your choice — perhaps by `id.keyword`:

```json
POST my-index/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.buckets.key,aggregations.*.buckets.children.hits.hits._source
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_parent_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parent_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "children": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [             <---
              {
                "id.keyword": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, you can [control the order](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) of the top-level, terms aggregation too.